# Como puedo hacer la validación de un RFC con JSP y primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hola necesito capturar un RFC con formato “AAAA-######-NNN” donde "N" puede ser un numero o digito, como lo puedo hacer?
tengo el RFC en un p:inputMask con primefaces,pero no se como definir el mask para el formato

y como puedo validar la fecha para que la fecha máxima sea un día antes al de hoy, en mi Clase declare la fecha con Date, y cuando intento pasar los datos a una tabla no me aparece la  fecha,como puedo hacerle para que la muestre o que tipo de dato puedo utilizar para que la reconozca? igual use una etiqueta p:calendar

Comment: con JSF y primefaces

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías mostrarnos parte del código que estas utilizando?